# Hide entire list when all list items are hidden

Tags: jquery, list, hide

I have a photo gallery with a nav. When you select "photos" in the nav, it hides the videos. When you click "videos," it hides the photos.

There will be some instances where there are no videos and I want those empty rows to be hidden automatically.

The only problem is, I'm not sure how to target *only* the empty rows.

**Here is my HTML with a row that has no videos:**

```
<div id="right">
    <ul>
        <li id="gallery-all">All</li>
        <li id="gallery-photos">Photos</li>
        <li id="gallery-videos">Videos</li>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="gallery-content" id="2012_national">
    <ul class="row">
        <li class="gallery-photo">
            <a class="group" title="" rel="" href="images/IMG_0672.jpg"><img src="files/photo.jpg" alt="" /></a>
            <p>Caption goes here</p>
        </li>
        <li class="gallery-photo">
            <a class="group" title="" rel="" href="images/IMG_1474.jpg"><img src="files/video.jpg" alt="" /></a>
            <p>Caption goes here</p>
        </li>
        <li class="gallery-photo">
            <a class="group" title="" rel="" href="images/IMG_1724.jpg"><img src="files/photo.jpg" alt="" /></a>
            <p>Caption goes here</p>
        </li>
        <li class="gallery-photo">
            <a class="group" title="" rel="" href="images/IMG_1725.jpg"><img src="files/video.jpg" alt="" /></a>
            <p>Caption goes here</p>
        </li>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Here is my jQuery so far:**

```
//Hide empty rows
if($('.row').children(':visible').length == 0) {
    $('.row').hide();
};
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Woah wait, you're being confusing here. You want to hide the `ul` when it's empty or just hide the individual `li`s?

Comment: @Purmou I assume they mean to hide the li's as the code already hides the row.

Comment: Sorry if I was confusing. The CSS style sets a white background to each row. So when there are no list items visible(image thumbnails), I don't want to see the empty white rows. I just want them to not appear anymore.

Answer (score 2):

You could hide/show all `.row` lists by simply checking the length of their visible child list items within the anonymous function used to set the display of the list itself:

```
$(".row").css("display", function(){
  return $("li:visible", this).length ? "block" : "none" ;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// iterate over each child of row
$('.row').children().each( function()
{
    // checks the text of each li
    if ( $(this).text() == "" )
    {
        // hides the li
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
​
```

Answer (score 1):

Used to hide rows:

```
jQuery('.gallery-content .row').each(function(i, row) {
    if(jQuery('li', row).length == 0) {
        jQuery(row).hide();
    }
});
```

If you want to hide it from the navi you can use the following after the code below:

```
if(jQuery('.gallery-content .row:visible').length == 0) {
    jQuery('#right li#gallery-videos').hide();
} else {
    jQuery('#right li#gallery-videos').show();
}
```